# clojure access enum defined inside a java class

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am trying to use the [argon-jvm](https://github.com/phxql/argon2-jvm) library for hashing in my application.

By default this library uses `Argon2i`, However, I would like to use `Argon2id`. To do so, I need to pass the enum value `Argon2Factory.Argon2Types.Argon2id` to the overloaded `create` method in the `Argon2Factory` class. Source code for [Argon2Factory.java here](https://github.com/phxql/argon2-jvm/blob/master/src/main/java/de/mkammerer/argon2/Argon2Factory.java).

From the lein repl (affter adding `[de.mkammerer/argon2-jvm "2.4"]` as a dependency), I can do the following:

```
user=> (import 'de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory)
de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory
user=> (def argon2 (Argon2Factory/create))
#'user/argon2
user=> (def hashedPassword (.hash argon2 17 65536 1 "passwordToBeHashed"))
#'user/hashedPassword
user=> hashedPassword
"$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=17,p=1$zvr4dz+/mpNxj5MVMtBALA$8dbE49MKV3dDfMMswTtjlB+niOeryh4EmJWNd7lj3FI"
```

However, I am unable to access the `Argon2Types` enum values (to pass to the `Argon2Factory.create` method) defined inside the `Argon2Factory` class itself. Can somone please help me access this enum?

PS: Auto-complete in the repl at different stages:

```
user=> (de.mkammerer.argon2.
de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2              de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Advanced      de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Constants     de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory
de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Helper        de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2d             de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2i             de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2id
de.mkammerer.argon2.BaseArgon2          de.mkammerer.argon2.jna.Argon2Library   de.mkammerer.argon2.jna.Argon2_type     de.mkammerer.argon2.jna.JnaUint32
de.mkammerer.argon2.jna.Size_t
user=> (de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory/create
de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory/create           de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory/createAdvanced
```

PPS: I will submit a pull request to this project with the Argon2Types enum defined in a .java file of its own, but in the meanntime, I would still like to know if accessing such enums is possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a REPL, try:

```
(import 'de.mkammerer.argon2.Argon2Factory$Argon2Types)
```

That works for me.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Now I can do:
`(def argon2 (Argon2Factory/create Argon2Factory$Argon2Types/ARGON2id))`